# I need help Unit Testing JsonResults in MVC.Net site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I am getting an error trying to Unit Test a JsonResult in my MVC.Net application.

I see that I am retrieving data using dynamic in my test, but when I do an Assert.AreEqual I get an error.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I fix this?

I have included the code I use in my unit test as well as the error that I am getting (see images below):

**CODE USED IN UNIT TEST**

```
   [TestMethod]
   public void getStatusesInfoTESTTest()
   {
       const int statusID = 12;
       MasterDataController controller = new MasterDataController();
       var result = controller.getStatusInfoTEST(statusID) as JsonResult;
       dynamic data = result.Data;
       Assert.AreEqual("TESTING 123", data.MasterDataDescription);
    }
```

**ERROR I GET:**

[IMAGE OF ERROR I GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRQUb.png)

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

*An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code*

**IMAGE OF THE DATA I GET BACK**
[IMAGE OF RETURNED DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVXUP.png)

Thanks for your help,
mrotor

Comment: Show the method under test. `getStatusInfoTEST` is the data a concrete type or an anonymous type?

Answer (score 0):

You should extract your controller's logic to some form of Service Class. This makes unit testing significantly easier.

The controller should just focus on taking the Service's raw value (probably a dictionary or IList or whatever) and abstract it into the JSON object.

Then you can just focus on unit testing the service much easier.

I've always been of the opinion that if you are unit testing your Controller's, you're doing it wrong. Models and Services should be unit tested, Controller's just bind the two together, but shouldn't have anything involving testable since their logic is implicit.

This helps you detangle your layers.